# WSO2 SSO always redirects to localhost:9443/samlsso

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 identity server (on port 9443) and enterprise service bus (ESB, on port 9444). I configured ESB to use IS SSO. But everytime I try to login into ESB it redirects me to IS and there it redirects me to URL localhost:9443/samlsso.

I already tried changing this URL in identities.xml and carbon.xml without access.

Where can I configure the redirection address?

In carbon.xml I specified the hostname as "HostName" and "MgtHostName". But IS still uses localhost.

Thanks!

Comment: you meant the when you provide the correct user/password,  it again redirect to  "localhost:9443/samlsso" ?  not to the ESB console?

Comment: No, I have no change to enter credentials. When I try to access the server on IP:9444/carbon I shortly see a message "Loading WSO2 StratosLive..." and then the 404 not found thrown by localhost:9443/samlsso.

Comment: Normally if you are running both servers in localhost,  you do not need to change WSO2IS's config file..  it would work usually...   9443/samlsso must be, if WSO2IS has properly started.. could you see any logs in wso2carbon.log  file... ?   I hope you followed this  https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Enabling+SSO+for+WSO2+Servers

Comment: Yeah, that's working. But I want to access the server from another client. And on this client, localhost is not right. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.

I did a search+replace over all XML documents inside the IS and ESB package and replaced all "localhost" by my hostname.

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 has a script located at:
`<IOTS_HOME>/scripts`

run
`./change-ip.sh`

> Tip: The script will find and replace the IP address given in argument1 (localhost) with the IP address given as argument2 (10.10.10.14), in the necessary configuration files.

[Check Docs to configure Hostname](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Configuring+the+IP+or+Hostname#ConfiguringtheIPorHostname-ConfiguringtheIPorhostnamemanually)

Comment: `change-ip.sh` is definitely a great help; wish I had discovered it earlier.  Make sure you run it on a clean extract of the software.  That said, WSO2's method of generating URLs on the fly and sticking those into `form` elements to perform browser-based redirection is nothing short of barmy, particularly if you try to run this shtuff behind a reverse proxy... Whilst it seems possible to deal with the hostname aspect with the above script, getting rid of that insistent `9443` port seems nigh on impossible.  I ended up having to PAT it on the perimeter and at very long last, it works... pfeww

Answer (score 2):

SSO configuration should in /repository/conf/security/authenticators.xml as follows to change the hostname of redirection url of Identity Server,

```
<Authenticator name="SAML2SSOAuthenticator" disabled="false">
    <Priority>1</Priority>
    <Config>
        <Parameter name="LoginPage">/carbon/admin/login.jsp</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="ServiceProviderID">carbonServer</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="IdentityProviderSSOServiceURL">https://<HostNameOfIdentitiyServer>:9443/samlsso</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="NameIDPolicyFormat">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</Parameter>
        <Parameter name="AssertionConsumerServiceURL">https://<HostNameOfIdentitiyServer>:9443/acs</Parameter>
     </Config>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the identity.xml there's a SSOService/IdentityProviderURL tag, that one seems important for SAML authentication.

Answer (score 0):

carbon.xml file under /repository/conf folder.

Change `<HostName>localhost</HostName>` to your IP.

```
<HostName>x.x.x.x</HostName>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the URL of your VM in system32/drivers/etc/hosts and map it to localhost.

Change the hosts file and map localhost to Ip-address of your VM where WSO2 is running.