# Redirection to localhost

Tags: wso2

i've installed wso2 iot server on my server running CentOS. I can acces the app with my server's ip (https://serverip:9443/carbon/) i can log as admin everything is fine but when a i want to acces device manager page (/devicemgt) i'm redirected to identity server localhost:9443/samlsso which of course doesn't exits.

I've edited the carbon.xml file with my server ip and restarted everything but it stills redirecting me to localhost.

```
<HostName>server_ip</HostName>
<MgtHostName>server_ip</MgtHostName>
```

How to resolve this ?

Moreover i've replace all occurences of "localhost:9443/samlsso" in every files without effect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in IdentityProvider configuration. You need to see file like  identity.xml 
It contained something like:

```
<SSOService><IdentityProviderURL>https://localhost:9443/samlsso</IdentityProviderURL>
```

And there is same questions as your: [WSO2 SSO always redirects to localhost:9443/samlsso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853721/wso2-sso-always-redirects-to-localhost9443-samlsso)